# TStringList's addObject method

Tags: delphi

I want to know what this method call does:

```
stringList.addObject(String,Object);
```

I also want to know what this property does:

```
stringList.Objects[i]
```

It looks like key,value pair while adding. But while retrieving in a loop what gets retrieved?

I also see items[i] call.

I am confused with TStringList operations and TList operations.

Comment: This is really a relic of ancient pre-generics Delphi. It doesn't make sense nowadays to use such crude typeless mechanisms. The generic `TList<T>` supersedes this technique.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is ancient, but usefull for users without access to the newer versions of delphi (>=2009). Also the OP doesn't specify the Delphi version which is using.

Comment: @RRUZ Exactly. Use it pre-generics, but please stop it once you have moved beyond.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree with you.

Comment: @David, are you suggesting re-writing perfectly functional code written in < D2009 when upgrading to D2009 and up for no reason other than to move to generics for this type of code? If not, then understanding this code (even if you're now using a version with generics) is important if for nothing but maintenance. I agree that *new* code written should use newer functionality, but you should clarify that was what you intended to say. :)

Comment: @Ken You re-write it when you next work in that area. But it's important to devote resources to such house-keeping.

Comment: Absolutely disagree, if the code is working and well-tested. Rewriting for the sake of rewriting is wrong, IMO. If functionality needs to change drastically, where it's worth the risk of introducing new bugs (and adding new overhead), fine. If it's just minor work or functional changes, like my grandpa said "Don't fix what ain't broke". :)

Comment: I agree with Ken, and his answer. Even Embarcadero did not rewrite the VCL using generics when they could have do it. Even worse, FireMonkey is also full of old fashioned code from DXScene Delphi 6 compatibiliy (e.g. still using `WideString` instead of `UnicodeString`). If the "official standard code" is not using generics nor even cleaned code... as most of us, they just want to make it right! So clean only on rewrite, not cleaning when you want it to be just cleaner or fashioned. Adding test-driven methods does make sense. Using generics does not *per se*. "What for" is better than "how".

Comment: @Arnaud That's what I meant by "You re-write it when you next work in that area."

Answer (score 19):

It adds a pair of items: an entry in the `TStringList.Strings` list, and a matching `TObject` in the `TStringList.Objects` list.

This allows you to, for instance, store a list of strings that supply a name for the item, and an object that is the class containing the  matching item.

```
type
  TPerson=class
    FFirstName, FLastName: string;
    FDOB: TDateTime;
    FID: Integer;
  private
    function GetDOBAsString: string;
    function GetFullName: string;
  published
    property FirstName: string read FFirstName write FFirstName;
    property LastName: string read FLastName write FLastName;
    property DOB: TDateTime read FDOB write FDOB;
    property DOBString: string read GetDOBAsString;
    property FullName: string read GetFullName;
    property ID: Integer read FID write FID;
  end;

implementation

{TPerson}
function TPerson.GetDOBAsString: string;
begin
  Result := 'Unknown';
  if FDOB <> 0 then
    Result := DateToStr(FDOB);
end;

function TPerson.GetFullName: string;
begin
  Result := FFirstName + ' ' + FLastName; // Or FLastName + ', ' + FFirstName
end;

var
  PersonList: TStringList;
  Person: TPerson;
  i: Integer;
begin
  PersonList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      Person := TPerson.Create;
      Person.FirstName := 'John';
      Person.LastName := Format('Smith-%d', [i]); // Obviously, 'Smith-1' isn't a common last name.
      Person.DOB := Date() - RandRange(1500, 3000);  // Make up a date of birth
      Person.ID := i;
      PersonList.AddObject(Person.LastName, Person);
    end;

    // Find 'Smith-06'
    i := PersonList.IndexOf('Smith-06');
    if i > -1 then
    begin
      Person := TPerson(PersonList.Objects[i]);
      ShowMessage(Format('Full Name: %s, ID: %d, DOB: %s',
                         [Person.FullName, Person.ID, Person.DOBString]));
    end;
  finally
    for i := 0 to PersonList.Count - 1 do
      PersonList.Objects[i].Free;
    PersonList.Free;
  end;
```

This is clearly a contrived example, as it's not something you'd really find useful. It demonstrates the concept, though.

Another handy use is for storing an integer value along with a string (for instance, showing a list of items in a `TComboBox` or `TListBox` and a corresponding ID for use in a database query). In this case, you just have to typecast the integer (or anything else that is SizeOf(Pointer)) in the `Objects` array.

```
// Assuming LBox is a TListBox on a form:
while not QryItems.Eof do
begin
  LBox.Items.AddObject(QryItem.Fields[0].AsString, TObject(QryItem.Fields[1[.AsInteger));
  QryItems.Next;
end;

// User makes selection from LBox
i := LBox.ItemIndex;
if i > -1 then
begin
  ID := Integer(LBox.Items.Objects[i]);
  QryDetails.ParamByName('ItemID').AsInteger := ID;
  // Open query and get info.
end;
```

In the case of storing things other than an actual `TObject`, you don't need to free the contents. Since they're not real objects, there's nothing to free except the `TStringList` itself.

Comment: Newer Delphi versions have a TStringList with an `OwnsObjects` property (and constructor parameter) much like TObjectList. If that is set to true, you don't need to, in fact you shouldn't, free the instances before freeing the list.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what happens to the objects when for example `stringListB := stringListA`. Does stringListB.Objects take a copy of the pointer to the original objects? Does this mean that when we then want `stringListA` freed, we should not free one by one its assigned Objects?

Comment: @VassilisGr: In the code above, *there are no objects*. They're integers, so there's nothing to free. Using `stringListB := stringListA;` is not a copy; it assigns a reference to `stringListA` into the variable `stringListB`. IOW, they're the same thing, being referenced by two variables. There is no second copy of the `Objects`, because there is no second copy of the stringlist. If the objects aren't real objects, there's no reason to free anything (as the last paragraph of my answer clearly states).

Comment: @Ken White, I was referring in a case of real objects. I agree of course with you. I'm leaving out the objects for now! Why this code works just fine? Because `Items` is a TListbox's property? And how exactly does it handle the assigment in this case? `slA:=TStringList.create; slA.add('A'); ListBox1.Items := slA; slA.Free; ShowMessage(ListBox1.Items[0]);`. If it's just a reference, by freeing `stA`, `ListBox1.Items` shouldn't contain any values (at least). IF instead of ListBox we use another TStringList instance, the code crashes as you said. My first question developed using `TListBox.Items`

Comment: @VassilisGr: No, your code is wrong. :) `slA := TStringList.Create; slA.Add('A'); ListBox1.Items.Assign(slA); slA.Free;` is the proper way (or replace `Assign` with `ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(slA);`. The problem is that `Items := slA;` just gets a second reference to `slA` (they're the same object); therefore, `slA.Free;` makes the **reference** contained in `ListBox1.Items` invalid, because **they're the same thing**. I said that before in my last comment. (If you need more information about how this all works, post your own new question; it's not appropriate for comments to this one.

Comment: @KenWhite The code I posted works but **it should not** as we free the one and only object referenced by `.Items` and `slA`, with `slA.Free` and the question is why. Anyway thanks for your answers and time. I may post a new question about this. Thanks again.

Comment: @KenWhite In the first code, it should be `Person := TPerson(PersonList.objects[i]);` If I may.

Comment: @EricBELLION: No, it shouldn't. The code I've posted is correct. The code you suggest would be used when retrieving a `TPerson` from `TPersonList`, which the code I posted does not do.

Answer (score 5):

The [`AddObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TStringList.AddObject) method lets you store a TObject address (pointer) associated to the string stored in the Item property. the [`Objects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TStrings.Objects) property is for access the stored objects.

Check this simple samplem that uses the `AddObject` to store an integer value associated to each string.

```
var
 List : TStringList;
 I    : integer;
begin
  try
    List:=TStringList.Create;
    try
      List.AddObject('Item 1', TObject(332));
      List.AddObject('Item 2', TObject(345));
      List.AddObject('Item 3', TObject(644));
      List.AddObject('Item 4', TObject(894));

      for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
        Writeln(Format('The item %d contains the string "%s" and the integer value %d',[I, List[I], Integer(List.Objects[i])]));
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Yes, TStringList.Objects[] can be used to store values. But remember that with XE2 the pointer size is not always equal to the integer size!

Comment: Indeed, but if you uses x64 the pointer is 8 bytes size and perfectly can hold a integer which always is of 4 bytes size.

Comment: If you are using a delphi before TStringList had an `OwnsObjects` property (and constructor parameter) and you are not merely storing values but instance references, then you would have to free any instances you put in those object references before freeing the StringList itself (unless of course those instances were owned by something else).

Answer (score 2):

TStringList is  more than a list of strings.

It can be used for name value pairs:

```
stringlist.Values['apple'] := 'one';
stringlist.Values['banana'] := 'two';
```

But it can also be used to associate strings with any object (or any pointer).

```
stringlist.AddObject('apple', TFruit.Create);
stringlist.AddObject('banana', TFruit.Create);


i := stringlist.IndexOf('apple');
if i >= 0 then
  myfruit := stringlist.Objects[i] as TFruit;
```

TList is a list that stores pointers. They are not associated with strings.

Comment: -1 You *shall* mention in your answer that any allocated object (`TFuit.Create`) must be released (`for i := 0 to stringlist.Count-1 do stringList.Objects[i].Free;` or `OwnsObjects` property) - it is not a good idea to use `TStringList` to store just created objects. You can use it with objects which have VCL-managed ownership or have there own lifetime. OP seems to be unexperimented, so your answer should at least mention that (like Ken White`s).