# Delphi - how to implement sorted table of integers and strings, sorted by integer?

Tags: string, sorting, delphi

I'd like to create a table with each row consisting of an integer and a string. The table should be sorted by the integer. The end goal is to extract the "n" strings with the smallest associated integer.

TStringlist isn't quite right because it is only a single string. They have Name-value pairs but they sort in the wrong order - I want value-name, sorted by value. 
TDictionary is not sorted and cannot be sorted (other than by hash, which they are)

I suppose I could format the integer into a string long enough to hold the largest integer with leading zeros, and concatenate that onto the start of the rest of the string data in a TStringList, but that seems ugly. Is there a more elegant approach to implement this table, sorted on the integer part?

Comment: You can switch to using a record type, and use a TList of those records and use a custom comparer to use for sorting. Or use a TStringList, store the integers in the Objects, and use a custom sort to sort by those integers instead of on the strings. (An example of storing integers in TStringList.Objects is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8947633/62576); see the second code snippet.)

Comment: Don't be afraid of defining types. Just because you have a RAD tool you don't have to stick to the types from the library.

Comment: @KenWhite TList<T> is good for data that is rarely changed. Maybe he better stick with a double-linked lists instead. Depending on working patterns

Answer (score 2):

A string list will still work, just cast your integer to the object field.

```
function SortStringListByObject(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if Integer(List.Objects[Index1]) = Integer(List.Objects[Index2])
  then result := 0
  else
    if Integer(List.Objects[Index1]) < Integer(List.Objects[Index2])
    then result := -1
    else result := 1;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  x: Integer;
begin
  StartTime := Now;
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // add some objects (and strings)
    sl.AddObject('One',TObject(3));
    sl.AddObject('Two',TObject(2));
    sl.AddObject('Three',TObject(1));

    // sory by my function
    sl.CustomSort(SortStringListByObject);

    // show results
    for x := 0 to sl.count-1 do begin
      Memo1.lines.Add(sl[x]);
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note this this will only work on desktop compilers. Casting an integer to and from object is not allowed in the mobile compilers.